# Image saved in blob returns net error::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I’m trying to migrate my app from Electron to Angular, my goal is to show an image uploaded by a user and to do this I did this :

**page.component.ts**

```
 uploadImageFile(){
    fileDialog({}, files =>{ //I use the fileDialog library that returns a FileList
      if(files[0])
      {
        this.filePath=URL.createObjectURL(files[0])
      return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this.filePath)
      }else{console.log(":/"); return false};
    })
}
```

**page.component.html**

```
img src="{{filePath}}" ngif="filePath" class="image2" width="200" height="250">
```

But the program returns this error:

```
WARNING: sanitizing unsafe URL value blob:http://localhost:4200/3f4bdf10-8080-4f4b-ba3f-15a7f85c6d69 (see https://g.co/ng/security#xss)

GET unsafe:blob:http://localhost:4200/3f4bdf10-8080-4f4b-ba3f-15a7f85c6d69 net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

Any advice on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Bypass security and trust the given value to be a safe for style URL and Resource URL

In this case you need to use `bypassSecurityTrustUrl` which means

> a value that can be used in hyperlinks or `<img src>`

`bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl` which means

> a location that may be used to load executable code from, like
> `<script src>`, or `<iframe src>`.

I hope you are clear with this solution

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but unfortunately the program produces the same two errors